# How to remove these special ascii characters from string in python?

Tags: python

```
string='IÃƒÂ¢Ã‚Â€Ã‚Â™m celebrating my sixth month anniversary of no longer being a customer of Star Wars. IÃƒÂ¢Ã‚Â€Ã‚Â™ve saved a lot of money'
```

From the above string i want to get rid of all the special characters.

Comment: Read the string using the correct encoding, probably UTF-8.

Comment: *All* characters are special.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you simply want to remove all non-ASCII characters from `string`:

```
print(''.join(c for c in string if ord(c) < 128))
```

This outputs:

```
Im celebrating my sixth month anniversary of no longer being a customer of Star Wars. Ive saved a lot of money
```

However, it's better that you find out what the encoding of your original string is and use [`bytes.decode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) to convert it to its original content with nothing removed.